# Archive with specific keyword by category sorted by date

Tags: pages, archives, sort

I need help to create a template for an archive with specific a keyword by category sorted by date. This is the code for my archive page so far: http://pastebin.com/WEjNGhJ1

My client wants every navigation menu item to go to an archive page for that particular keyword. Example: "Beauty" navigation location will display the beauty category's posts, sorted by date, using the archive page format.

My navigation menu is in the sidebar which you can see here on my site: http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/livelong

Comment: anybody here?? I really need to accomplish this task please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories will use category.php by default as their archive template (site.com/category/category-name). Customize that with the code you've used here, rather than using a 'page template'.

If you don't want it to say category/ in the URL there are plugins or functions.php code you can use to remove it that can be found numerous times in the archive here.

Comment: It's category.php I'm just trying to view it as a page. Ok, I already removed the page template comment. here's the code .. http://pastebin.com/YYddNi0g now, is there anywat to customize my code to create an archive with specific keyword by category sorted by date, keywords are in navigation as you see on my posted website.. thanks..

Comment: What does this "It's category.php I'm just trying to view it as a page." mean? 

Category archives aren't 'pages' in the WordPress sense.